# Computed function returns undefined with reactive data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am kind of new with Vue 3 and Vue ecosystem entirely and I stuck with sht. Here's the problem.

I have an reactive state that I fill with my form code's here:

```
const formData = reactive({
      some: '',
      key: '',
      value: '',
      pairs: number,
    });
```

and I have this object that I need to fill because I change some data for my API here's that code.

```
const formDataForApi: ComputedRef<FormDataObjectModel> =
      computed(() => ({
        some: formData.some,
        key: alterTheKeyValueFunction(formData.key),
        value: formData.value,
        pair: formatPairData(formData.pair)
      }));
```

and at the click function I try to send the formDataForApi.value to my api but it's always undefined.

How can I fix this. BTW these are all in setup function but I only return formHandle function.

This is also the component.

```
<script lang="ts">
import {
  computed,
  ComputedRef,
  defineComponent,
  onMounted,
  reactive,
  watch,
} from "vue";

import { alterTheKeyValueFunction } from 'somewhere'

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SomeComponent",
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    onMounted(async () => {
      await getSthFromAnotherAPI()
    });


    const formatPairData = computed(() => {
      if (!pair.value) return;
      return { pair: formData.pair};
    });

  const formData = reactive({
      some: '',
      key: '',
      value: '',
      pairs: number,
    });
  const formDataForApi: ComputedRef<FormDataObjectModel> =
      computed(() => ({
        some: formData.some,
        key: alterTheKeyValueFunction(formData.key),
        value: formData.value,
        ...formatPairData(formData.pair)
      }));


    const formSubmitHandler = async () => {
      //here the form submitter 
    };

    return {

      formData,
      formSubmitHandler,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

alterTheKeyValueFunction it's an util func that takes an object that contains 3 string key value pairs and returns interpolated string.

eg: {
abc: "hello:,
def: "world
}

### returns hello world.

on the other hand formatPairData() if the pair is filled in the form it returns that value otherwise it returns nothing so when you submit form you don't send the pair data.

Comment: Please show the component with the setup and methods

Comment: still missing context for mysterious variables/functions: `sth`, `alterTheKeyValueFunction`, etc. so we're still missing the full picture but the thing that pops out at me is you're calling computed property `formatPairData` like a method (passing a param) which is not valid (it's *technically* possible but not recommended when a method can work just as well).  I would also suggest turning `formDataForApi` into an actual function with return value so you can break things into multiple statements you can debug one by one with console.logs and/or devtools. it's a one liner trying to do too much.

Comment: Just a side note: You should think of formatting your code a bit better. You could use pettier which will auto-format your code based on settings. Then the code is also easier to read and to understand. If you want to understand what is wrong with your code, try to read every line and try to understand, what it does. For instance `await getSthFromAnotherAPI()` does not make any sense, as it is not assigned to any variable or not receiving any value.

Comment: Well since I am bound by a confidentiality agreement I had to change the code but you're right getSthFromAnotherApi() isn't relevant to my question but it's also not relevant with composition API also I am using prettier with my original code this is a reducted version of it. But the problem here is this was working normally with 3.0.1 version of the vue then we added the i18n package and upgraded the vue to 3.2.45 version and it started to create problems. BTW I tried changing the arrow functions to normal functions didn't worked.

Comment: What you posted doesn't work. `pair` is `undefined` in `formatPairData` and so is `number` in `formData`. Could you please create a *runnable* [mcve], reproducing the issue without throwing any errors in console (which currently seems to be the only reason why your component is not working). You are only bound by confidentiality agreement if you post something sensitive. Nobody's stopping you from anonymising your data/method names or whatever you think is confidential in your app. Remember you're the one asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, just a few smaller issues:

- you define `formData.pairs` (plural) but access it as `formData.pair` (singular)
- computed properties are refs, not functions, so `formatPairData(formData.pair)` does not work
- when destructuring the computed `formatPairData`, you need to destructure the ref's value, not the ref itself, so it should be `....unref(formatPairData)`
- inside the function that builds the computed `formatPairData`, you access the pair value as `pair.value` in the `if`, but it needs to be `formData.pair`

In the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-leavitt-l83ib7?file=/src/components/SomeComponent.vue), this seems to work as expected:

```
import { computed, defineComponent, reactive, unref } from "vue";

const alterTheKeyValueFunction = (key) => "altered key " + key;

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SomeComponent",
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const formatPairData = computed(() => {
      if (!formData.pair) return {};  // <--- access as formData.pair
      return { pair: formData.pair };
    });

    const formData = reactive({
      some: "inital some",
      key: "initial key",
      value: "inital value",
      pair: -1, // <---- check "pairs" vs "pair"
    });

    const formDataForApi = computed(() => ({
      some: formData.some,
      key: alterTheKeyValueFunction(formData.key),
      value: formData.value,
      ...unref(formatPairData), // <---- destructure computed ref
    }));

    return {
      formData,
      formDataForApi,
    };
  },
});
```